# Building gRPC with windows 10 and QT creator - C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to build gRPC library with Windows 10 with QT. Im using QT creator 5.15.2 MSVC 2019 compiler kit. I installed protobuf and grpc using vcpkg. I can able to successfully test protobuf libraries. But failing to do so with gRPC.

Getting the following error.

grpc.lib(check_gcp_environment_windows.cc.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **imp_RegGetValueA referenced in function "bool **cdecl grpc_core::internal::check_windows_registry_product_name(struct HKEY** *,char const *,char const *)" (?check_windows_registry_product_name@internal@grpc_core@@YA_NPEAUHKEY**@@PEBD1@Z)

I have tried linking the libraries one by one in QT like below. Attached my .pro file here

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++17 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/zlibd.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/abseil_dll.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_cord_internal.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_cordz_functions.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_cordz_handle.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_cordz_info.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_cordz_sample_token.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags_commandlineflag.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags_commandlineflag_internal.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags_config.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags_internal.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags_marshalling.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags_parse.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags_private_handle_accessor.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags_program_name.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags_reflection.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags_usage.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_flags_usage_internal.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_low_level_hash.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_random_internal_distribution_test_util.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_statusor.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/absl_strerror.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/address_sorting.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/cares.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/descriptor_upb_proto.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/gpr.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/grpc.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/grpc_plugin_support.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/grpc_unsecure.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/grpc++.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/grpc++_alts.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/grpc++_error_details.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/grpc++_reflection.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/grpc++_unsecure.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/grpcpp_channelz.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/libcrypto.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/libprotobufd.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/libprotobuf-lited.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/libprotocd.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/libssl.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/re2.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/upb.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/upb_collections.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/upb_extension_registry.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/upb_fastdecode.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/upb_json.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/upb_mini_table.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/upb_reflection.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/upb_textformat.lib
LIBS += C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/upb_utf8_range.lib


INCLUDEPATH += C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include

HEADERS += \
        helloworld.grpc.pb.h \
        helloworld.pb.h

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        helloworld.grpc.pb.cc \
        helloworld.pb.cc


# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

There were few errors w.r.2 ws2_32 lib. which I have neglected using the following pragma statement.

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

But the error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegGetValueA referenced in function . I couldnt find any. I believe its something related to re2.lib linked. Kindly add your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: [`RegGetValueA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluea#requirements) requires linking with `Advapi32.lib`

Comment: Thanks RIichard. That worked. I added '' LIBS += -ladvapi32 '' .